# Correct activations and loss functions for binary classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am doing a binary image classification (two mutually exclusive classes) with keras and tensorflow and have been looking at the following options for the loss function and output layer activation:

1. Categorical cross-entropy and softmax function with 2 neurons output
2. Binary cross-entropy and softmax function with 2 neurons output
3. Categorical cross-entropy and sigmoid function with 2 neurons output
4. Binary cross-entropy and sigmoid function with 1 neuron output

Before all of them there are several convolutional layers and Flatten().

Do they all make sense? I expect 1 and 4 do, but I want to know more about the other 2 as well, because 2 seems to work fine but I don't know if it is correct.